# Audio recording formats in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I want to record audio in my iphone app, I found that the recording format is AAC
what are the other formats I can do record,
How to record audio in MP3 format, is there any tutorial for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no only acc,m4a format is there. you can use converters later after recording even itunes have option to convert it